# How does this become a recursive construct?

Tags: javascript, recursion

app using and older version of prototype.js (1.3), have this :

```
Object.extend = function(destination, source) {
  for (property in source) {
    destination[property] = source[property];
  }
  return destination;
}

Object.prototype.extend = function(object) {
  return Object.extend.apply(this, [this, object]);
}
```

Now normally this works ok, but sometimes that last function turns recursive and calls itself until call stack size is exceeded.
Granted I am not a javascript wizard so this may be fairly obvious to someone else.
Would someone care to shed some light on this?

Comment: If Object.extend isn't defined, then Object.prototype.extend will become recursive. Demo code?

Comment: I don't believe that that function, as posted here, will "turn recursive" - it never calls itself. Now, a "deep copy" version of such a function could run into a circular graph and go crazy, but the code posted isn't such a function.

Comment: But if Object.extend is not defined when you call the extend function it will not be used the one defined in the prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the property of an object with `myObject.propertyName` then JS first looks at the **own properties** of myObject. If one with that propertyName is found it's taken. Only when its not found there JS searches in the **prototype** (and later in the whole **prototype-chain**) if a property with that name exists there.

Thats why it's normally a bad idea to have a property `extend` directly on the object and another with same name on its prototype, because the latter ist **shadowed** by the first and therefor useless.

With the assignment `Object.extend = function() {...};` the function is set as an own property of the native Object-constructor. Now when you do `Object.extend(..)` that function gets executed, there may be an Object.prototype.extend or not.

**Only when there is no own property `extend`** the `.prototype.extend` comes into play and gets executed when doing `Object.extend(...)`. And what happens inside that prototype function ? First a look for Object's own `extend` and, not found, the call of `.prototype.extend`: recursion is there.

If that happens *sometimes* to you, then *at that times* Object.extend is undefined.